# What do the prefixes (ep and vb) in couchbase monitoring statistics mean?

Tags: monitoring, couchbase

While looking at the statistics for CouchBase monitoring, like `ep_queue_size`, `vb_num_eject_replicas`, `ep_warmup_value_count`, and `vb_active_curr_items`, I see that most of them are prefixed with `ep_` or `vb_`. I have not been able to find any explanation on what these prefixes mean.

I have tried searching the docs at https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/monitor/monitoring-cli.html but have found nothing. I think it might be that `ep_` stands for ephemeral bucket and `vb_` stands for vBucket, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ep` refers to **Eventually Persistent**, referring to the eventually persistent data layer of Couchbase. Reference to it is [here](https://github.com/couchbase/ep-engine).

`vb` refers to **vBucket**. Reference to it is [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbstats-intro.html).